# OAuth 2.0 google permissions dialog doesnt work properly on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I have wp7 app that should consume Google Latitude API. It requires my app to be authenticated with OAuth 2.0 access token. To archive that I'm using authentication flow for native applications (described here http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#IA). When my app navigates to Request for Permissions  page from within browser control and I'm clicking on "Allow access", the server respond to me with "Deniend error=acces_denied" page.
Google Latitude API is enabled on my apis console btw. Can anybody help me to determine where is the problem?

**[EDIT]**

Thanks to @gyurisc i figured out that it works on desktop browser, I have my access token. But there is still a mystery whats wrong with browser control of WP7! Why it returns "Access Denied" error if I allow access.

**[EDIT]**

I've posted an issue in Google Latitude Issue Tracker [OAuth 2.0 dialog doesnt work properly on WP7](http://code.google.com/p/latitude-api/issues/detail?id=25)

Comment: Shusha Did you try the same on desktop as well? It might be useful to try so you can find out if this comes from the authentication or this is wp7 specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary workaround from google team is to replace "account.google.com" to "sandbox.google.com". They will try to fix this bug asap on production server